# addEventListener "click" only runs once with if statement

Tags: javascript

I have an addEventListener for a dropdown menu and when I click it for the first time the menu appears, and if I click again it disappears correctly. However, after that if I try again nothing happens. If I get rid of the if statements and use a simple alert inside the function it works every time, but this if statement seems to be troublesome.

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",navigation);
function navigation() {
var navMenu = document.getElementById("navigation");
var list = document.getElementById("list");
if (navMenu.style.height == 0) {
    navMenu.style.height = "190px";
    list.style.display = "flex";
}
else {
    navMenu.style.height = "0";
    list.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: The returned value of the `height` property will be "0px" and not "0" in most browsers, so your condition _fails_ to check the value properly.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The element height is reported in pixels so updating the code like this should work.

```
if (navMenu.style.height === '0px') {
```

Here is a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOXAzd

Answer (score 1):

In the condition, change

`if (navMenu.style.height == 0)`

to

`if (navMenu.style.height == '0px')`

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but have you tried to do `= 0` instead of `= '0'`?

I hope this helped, good luck.